# Using Go Modules with packages that require "make install"

Tags: go

I have an external package that apart from the usual `go get`, needs to run `make install` in its `$GOPATH/src` directory in order to use it (performs some makefile and git magic).

Trying to use this package with modules means a copy of it is downloaded to the vendor library using `go mod vendor`. However, this copy is not a git repository so running `make install` inside the package's vendor folder fails.

Does this mean that the package cannot be used in a module and I have to revert to using GOPATH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean that the package cannot be used in a module

Yes.

Contact the author and make him to check in what the makefile does.